# README.rst not parsing on pypi but dose on testpypi

Tags: python, distutils, restructuredtext, pypi

After i released a new version of my package, for some reason pypi stopped showing the README.rst.

The changes were minimal, here is [the diff](https://github.com/urban48/debpackager/compare/v0.1.3...v0.2.2#diff-88b99bb28683bd5b7e3a204826ead112) between the two versions of the README.rst file.
I cant understand what broke it...

I've also tried to upload it to testpypi, and surprise surprise i can see it there perfectly.

link to [testpypi](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/debpackager/0.2.2)
link to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/debpackager/0.2.2)

any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure it out. Then I found this repo that just wrote the README to the long_description field. Worked for me.

https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/blob/master/setup.py#L68